# Can't access port 8080 on EC2 (AWS)

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just started a new AWS EC2 instance.  In the instance's security group I added a new rule to open port 8080.  I also stopped the iptables service on the instance, per another post.  So in theory this port should be wide open.

I started my RESTful service on 8080 and was able to access it locally via curl.

When I come in with curl remotely I get an error saying it couldn't connect to the host.

What else should I check to see if 8080 is truly open?

Comment: Security group rules sometimes take a few minutes to propagate, so first, try again. How does `telnet <external_instance_CNAME> 8080` return?

Answer (score 1):

> I started my RESTful service on 8080 and was able to access it locally via curl.

What kind of technology is your RESTful service based upon?

Many frameworks nowadays listen on [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (`127.0.0.1`) only, be it by default or by means of their examples, see e.g. the canonical [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) one (I realize that port `8080` hints towards Java/Tomcat, anyway):

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

The log message generated by starting this is *Server running at http://**127.0.0.1**:1337/* - the emphasized part is key here, i.e. the server has been configured to listen on the IP address `127.0.0.1` only, whereas you are trying to connect to it via your public [Amazon EC2 IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.

1. Listen `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.
2. Listen `127.0.0.1` and setup a proxy via, for example, `nginx`.

References:

- [*Warp connection failed unless using proxy*](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/warp-connection-failed-unless-using-proxy/52011)
- [*Why can't other computers access my web server on 127.0.0.1? [closed]*](https://serverfault.com/questions/387230/why-cant-other-computers-access-my-web-server-on-127-0-0-1)