# Beego running on AWS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, go, beego

I have tried running Beego on AWS, but no matter what I have tried, I can't seem to connect to port 8080, which is where Beego is running on. I'm not sure if it's an AWS or a Beego issue, but I can't seem to connect to port 80 either (I have tried to change the security group setting, including adding a new one to allow access to both ports). However, when I curl 127.0.0.1, a Beego template is there, but there is nothing at [my E2 instance](http://ec2-54-88-252-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com). I changed the app.conf file's httpaddr to 0.0.0.0, but that didn't seem to do much. How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you [`conf/app.conf`](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/master/example/beeapi/conf/app.conf) file:

```
httpaddr = localhost
```

By default, beego can be configured to listen to localhost only (as [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16186687/6309)).

[Other issues](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89386) include (for the AWS part):

- configuring security groups to permit inbound access on port 8080.
- disabled any Application firewalls like Windows Firewall or Iptables for that port?
- checking `netstat -anp|grep 80`  and `sudo iptables -L`

For ubuntu, the [OP dtrinh100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2704875/dtrinh100) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820721/beego-running-on-aws-issue/25820777?noredirect=1#comment40404272_25820777) having to:

> get it to work by disabling iptables, but since I'm running Ubuntu, it was a little different.
>   I used the iptables command from "[How to start/stop iptables on Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/129087/783)", which allowed me to turn off iptables in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have two security group, the default and launch. I have both ports 80 and 8080 opened on default and port 22 opened on launch. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @dtrinh100 no, but make sure your beego webapp isn't set to listen to only localhost, because then no amount of port opening would suffice to access said webserver.

Comment: @VonC How do I make sure it isn't set to only listen to only the localhost?

Comment: @dtrinh100 that is what the first part of my answer addresses

Comment: @dtrinh100 you should listen to the ec2 ip address (http://superuser.com/q/361320/141), or all addresses (for testing, as in http://superuser.com/a/744804/141). But the point is: if by default beego is listening on localhost, no external message will get through (as explained, for instance, in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=258040#258040).

Comment: @VonC I have tried to make it listen to the ec2 IP address, but it won't let me bind to that address. I have also tried to make it listen to "0.0.0.0". In this case, it binds just fine, but I still can't access the ec2 IP address from my web browser (it no longer times out, but it simply just won't connect).

Comment: @dtrinh100 maybe some of the advices of https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=258040#258040 could help, regarding iptables.

Comment: @VonC I was able to get it to work by disabling iptables, but since I'm running Ubuntu, it was a little different than what was posted on the link you gave me.

Comment: @VonC I used the iptables command from http://serverfault.com/questions/129086/how-to-start-stop-iptables-on-ubuntu (first answer) which allowed me to turn off iptables in Ubuntu.

Comment: @dtrinh100 Good find. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.